# Keeping default value of extended styled-component if property value is false

Tags: javascript, typescript, ternary-operator, styled-components

My application uses Typescript and Styled-Components and has this (simplified) styled-component declaration:

```
const StyledComponent = styled(AnotherStyledComponent)`
    background-color: ${(p: any) => isTrue ? '#ede4dc' : null};
`
```

The reason why I have null as the second expression is because I want to keep the `background-color` of StyledComponent equal to the value of `background-color` of AnotherStyledComponent.

However, if I keep it this way, I get the error:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '(p: any) => "#ede4dc" | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation'.
>     Type '(p: any) => "#ede4dc" | null' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyArray | InterpolationFunction ...'.
>       Property 'flatMap' is missing in type '(p: any) => "#ede4dc" | null'.

Am I doing something wrong or this is a flaw on Styled-Component library side?

Comment: Right now you are not keeping the original color, but overwriting it with null. You will have to save the original color to a variable, and set that as the second expression.

Comment: Adding an empty string instead of null might help.